# Not sure what type of mistake I am making. CSS3 & Mobile display

Tags: html, css

I've finally been able to get my site back up and finish building it, yet I am not satisfied with the front end.

My current goal is have the the mobile display with 2 items in 2 rows.

But my issue is when I use the Chrome mobile view and my personal phone, it still copies the attributes from "fbox".

HTML:

```
<div id="row"1><div class="fbox mfbox" id="breast">test </div>
<div class="fbox mfbox" id="facial">test </div></div>

<div id="row2"><div class="fbox mfbox" id="body"> test</div>
<div class="fbox mfbox" id="surgery">test </div></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width:767px){
.mfbox{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
width:100%;
height:200px;
display:block;
}
.row1{
    clear:both;
}
.row2{
    clear:both;
}
}

.fbox{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
width:22%;
height:200px;
display:inline-block;
margin:10px;
}
```

I've added it to [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgw1a1om/1/), but it does not seem to produce the results my site does.

My site: Site Removed.

Comment: Always try add @media query at the end of your css code. Move `.fbox ` css above @media query..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write media query under the .fbox like below

---

```
.fbox{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    width:22%;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
}

#row1, #row2 {
    clear: none;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
 .mfbox{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
 }
 #row1{
    clear:both;
 }
 #row2{
    clear:both;
 }
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgw1a1om/4/)

In your case first .mfbox is applied good but after .mfbox there is another css .fbox so the css is replaced from .mfbox to .fbox, in that case you should apply midea query at the bottom.

Remove clear when outside of the media query,
and use `#` instead of `.` when using `id`
i.e. `#row1` instead of `.row1`

Comment: Hence the name 'Cascading Style Script'

Answer (score 1):

You said you want two items in a row. But your css

> .mfbox{
>       ...
>   **width:100%;**
>   **height:200px;**
>   display:block;
>   }
>   means only one item at a row with 100% width & height of 200px.

Also in your code you are getting issues because, you had two class, and in css you defined styling for both class in the order .mfbox & .fbox. So while applying css styling obviously it will take later defined style only.

However, if you want to apply different css for mobile view and different for desktop, its not necessary to use two classes. You can handle this with only one class & in css can handle with @media.

For example:

```
.fbox{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    width:22%;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
}
@media (max-width:767px){
   .fbox{
         width:100%;
         height:200px;
         display:block
    }
}
```